# Why kernel supports registering device of different major numbers in one call

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, driver, linux-device-driver

A block device driver could call `blk_register_region()` to claim responsibility for a larger range of device numbers. For example, in ramdisk driver's initialization, it calls blk_register_region to claim for all posible ram disks.

```
static int __init brd_init(void)
{
    // ...

    blk_register_region(MKDEV(RAMDISK_MAJOR, 0), 1UL << MINORBITS,
                  THIS_MODULE, brd_probe, NULL, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Drivers like ramdisk and floppy register with their own major device number (`RAMDISK_MAJOR / FLOPPY_MAJOR` defined in major.h). But I read the code
of blk_register_region and found this function supports registering device of different major numbers in one call.

Function blk_register_region simply wraps kobj_map. And kobj_map supports claiming up to 255 major devices in one invocation. Where dos this need come from?

```
void blk_register_region(dev_t devt, unsigned long range, struct module *module,
             struct kobject *(*probe)(dev_t, int *, void *),
             int (*lock)(dev_t, void *), void *data)
{
    kobj_map(bdev_map, devt, range, module, probe, lock, data);
}

int kobj_map(struct kobj_map *domain, dev_t dev, unsigned long range,
         struct module *module, kobj_probe_t *probe,
         int (*lock)(dev_t, void *), void *data)
{
    // calculate the range of major numbers
    unsigned n = MAJOR(dev + range - 1) - MAJOR(dev) + 1;
    unsigned index = MAJOR(dev);
    unsigned i;
    struct probe *p;

    if (n > 255)
        n = 255;

    p = kmalloc(sizeof(struct probe) * n, GFP_KERNEL);

    if (p == NULL)
        return -ENOMEM;
    // ....
}
```

Thanks in adance.

Answer (score 1):

`But I read the code of blk_register_region and found this function supports registering device of different major numbers in one call`

This is not actually the case. If you look carefully at the code, all of them get the same major number (see the line with my comment in the code below).

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++, p++) {
        p->owner = module;
        p->get = probe;
        p->lock = lock;
        p->dev = dev;      /* See the assigned device number */
        p->range = range;
        p->data = data;
}
```

As for the requirement of the supported behavior, check [this](https://lwn.net/Articles/25711/) LWN article **Driver porting: the gendisk interface**, section **Registering block device number ranges**.

Quoting directly from the article,

> A call to add_disk() implicitly allocates the a set of minor numbers
>   (under the given major number) from first_minor to
>   first_minor+minors-1. If your driver must only respond to operations
>   to disks that exist at initialization time, there is no need to worry
>   further about number allocation. Even the traditional call to
>   register_blkdev() is optional, and may be removed soon. Some drivers,
>   however, need to be able to claim responsibility for a larger range of
>   device numbers at initialization time.
>
> If this is your case, the answer is to call blk_register_region()

Few things to note here are (again from the article),

- `range` is the number of minor numbers to allocate.
- When blk_register_region() is called, it simply makes a note of the desired region and returns. Note that there can be more than one registration within a specific region! At lookup time, the most "specific" registration (the one with the smallest range) wins.

Comment: Thanks.  These lines `unsigned n = MAJOR(dev + range - 1) - MAJOR(dev) + 1; if (n > 255) {n = 255;}`  imply that var `n` (count of major numbers) may be larged than 255. So If `blk_register_region` only handles same major number, what's the need of these lines?